# Cannot access a URL on my backend due to Access / CORS issue in Spring 5

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I added in Security into my Spring app and suddenly I am getting CORS issues. I have tried many different CORS settings in Spring (see some of the commented out code). Nothing is working.

I am passing basic auth in my front end Angular app as so:

```
const httpOptions = {
headers: new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Basic mybase64basicauth'
  })
};

...
this.campaignsSubscription = this.http.get<Campaign[]>(this.campaignsUrl, httpOptions)
```

And I have my app configured for CrossOrigin both locally and globally.

Global:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
public class WebConfig implements WebFluxConfigurer {

   @Override
   public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

    registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
            .allowedMethods("PUT", "DELETE", "GET", "OPTIONS", "POST", "PATCH")
            .allowedHeaders("Authorization", "Content-Type")
            // .allowedHeaders("Content-Type")
            .allowCredentials(true).maxAge(3600);

    // Add more mappings...
   }
}
```

And locally:

```
/*@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200",
    allowedHeaders = "*",
    methods = { RequestMethod.DELETE, RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.HEAD, RequestMethod.OPTIONS, RequestMethod.PATCH, RequestMethod.PUT},
    allowCredentials = "true"
    )*/
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/campaign")
public class CampaignResource {

private CampaignRepository campaignRepository;

public CampaignResource(CampaignRepository campaignRepository) {
    this.campaignRepository = campaignRepository;
}


@GetMapping("/all")
public Flux<Campaign> getAll() {
    return campaignRepository
            .findAll();

 ...
```

But I get these errors in the Chrome console:

```
        zone.js:2969 OPTIONS http://localhost:8081/api/campaign/all 401 (Unauthorized)

   'http://localhost:8081/api/campaign/all' from origin 
   'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to 
   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access- 
    Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I know the basic auth is correct as it works in Postman.

Comment: @DavidGoate Yes: The port 4200 is what an Angular app runs on in development mode when you run ng serve. Also, its obviously served up via localhost. Both my Spring server and my front end are running on my local machine for dev purposes. I have spring running at http://localhost:8081

Comment: Request headers:
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Connection: keep-alive
DNT: 1
Host: localhost:8081
Origin: http://localhost:4200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36

Comment: I don't see an immediate issue. It's very similar to the config I use in a spring boot 1 project (not web flux). To be sure, if you remove the local `@CrossOrigin` applied to the endpoint and rely just on the global config does the behaviour change at all?

Comment: In case it helps, this is the configuration i used in spring boot 1 with spring mvc: https://pastebin.com/ignRZ0p0 The main difference being that I enable CORS via the security configuration adapter and define a bean of type `UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource` with name `corsConfigurationSource`. I am not sure what has to be done in webflux to get a similar setup though. This looks promising; https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux-cors I mainly wonder whether you mixture of local and global approach is somehow conflicting, maybe try removing the local annoation

Comment: If it were me, I'd first try without any cross origin annotation on the resource (just the global config) . If that fails, I'd try removing the global config and on the annotation explicitly set the appropriate attributes on the annotation. e.g. `@CrossOrigin(methods=, origins=, allowCredentials=true)` etc...

Comment: Thank you all for your help! It was your questions that helped me to narrow it down until I figured out the solution. @dur The answer given by your link is CLOSE but different due to Spring Versions, so I thought it prudent to post an answer which works with Spring 5.x. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

When using Spring Security 5.x...

The answer is two fold:

1) In your SecurityWebFilterChain you must add:

```
.pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()**strong text**
```

2) In your Resource you must add the following CORS statement:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200",
        allowedHeaders = "*",
        methods = { RequestMethod.DELETE, RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.HEAD, RequestMethod.OPTIONS, RequestMethod.PATCH, RequestMethod.PUT},
        allowCredentials = "true"
        )
```

Here is my complete SecurityConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain springWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .pathMatchers("/login", "/logout").permitAll()
                .pathMatchers("/i18n/**",
                        "/css/**",
                        "/fonts/**",
                        "/icons-reference/**",
                        "/img/**",
                        "/js/**",
                        "/vendor/**").permitAll()
                .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/api/**").authenticated()
                .anyExchange()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
               .formLogin()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                /*.loginPage("/login")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")*/
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .build();
    }


    //in case you want to encrypt password
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```